# ModuleNotFoundError: No Module Named 'apsheduler'

Tags: flask, python-3.8

***ERROR***:-- "**Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'apscheduler'
File "F:\Finel Year Project\project_bone\backend.py", line 9, in 
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler**"

I have installed the current version of apscheduler(3.6.3) and python(3.8) and also installed all the packages using command '**pip install APScheduler**', but still it was showing the same above error.

Answer (score 0):

Might be its issue of environment or python path, try executing

```
pip3 install apscheduler
```